# Global launch configuration in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

This seems like a simple thing, but I can't find an answer in the existing questions:

How do you add a global argument to all your present and existing run or debug configurations?  In my case, I need a VM argument, but I see that this could be useful for runline arguments as well.

Basically, every time I create a unit test I need to create a configuration (or run, which creates one), and then manually edit each one with the same VM argument.  This seems silly for such a good tool.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ouch: [7-years bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=41353), asking for running configuration template, precisely for that kind or reason.

[This thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.tools.jdt/msg07770.html) proposes an interesting workaround, based on duplicating a fake configuration based on string substitution:

> 1. You can define variables in `Window->Preferences->Run/Debug->String Substitution`. For example you can define a `projectName_log4j` variable with the
>      correct `-Dlog4j.configuration=...` value.
>      In a run configuration you can use `${projectName_log4j}` and you don't have to remember the real value.
> 2. You can define a project-specific "empty" run configuration.
>      Set the project and the arguments fields in this configuration but not the main class. If you have to create a new run configuration for this project select this one and use 'Duplicate' from its popup-menu to copy this configuration.
>      You have to simply set the main class and the program arguments.
>
> Also you can combine both solutions: use a variable and define an "empty"
>   run configuration which use this variable. The great advantage in this case
>   is when you begin to use a different log4j config file you have to change
>   only the variable declaration.

Not ideal, but it may alleviate your process.

Comment: Hrm both solutions are harder than what I do now!  I love the end of the bug description where they say it's just too hard to add basic functionality.

Comment: It's not a good answer for me, but wins by virtue of being the only one ;)

Answer (score 11):

This is not true. You can add the VM arguments to the JRE definition. This is exactly what it is for. I use it myself so that assertions are enabled and heap is 1024mb on every run, even future ones.

Comment: If it's only for the assertions, there is a checkbox in Preference -> JUnit -> [x] Add '-ea' to VM arguments when creating a new JUnit Launch Configuration.